# Sys.Log numbers in binary notation in android?

Tags: android, binary, logging, notation

Is it possible to log numbers in binary notation?

For example Logbinary(0x3) should give my 0111 when using signed notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Integer.toBinaryString(yourint);
```

or

```
Long.toBinaryString(yourint);
```

to convert your number to a binary string which you can log.